# comment host file rows containing a string, if not already commented

Tags: bash, sed, comments, hosts

I am attempting to comment several entries in my [/etc/hosts] file using sed.   I have the following command which works great:

```
 sed -i$(date +%s).bak '/devops/,/devops/s/^/# /' /etc/hosts
```

My problem comes when i re-run the script containing the above line,  my commented lines get a new comment.       How can I add the ability to skip commented [^#] rows?

Thank you, 
Lars

Comment: `sed -i$(date +%s).bak '/^[^#]*devops/s/^/# /' /etc/hosts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment only those lines which are not already commented:

```
sed -i$(date +%s).bak '/^[^#]*devops/s/^/# /' /etc/hosts
```